# RestAssured Not able to extract response

Tags: rest-assured, rest, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am trying to get the `id_token.basic` value but its not working because of `.basic`

```
{
    "user_id": "12345",
    "id_tokens": [

        {
            "id_token.basic": "myid123"
        }
    ]

}
```

Tried the below, but because of `.basic` its not working.

```
response.jsonPath().get("id_tokens[0].id_token.basic")
```

I am able to retrieve `user_id` using:

```
response.jsonPath().get("user_id")
```

Comment: Treat it as a single string `get("id_tokens[0].'id_token.basic'")`

Comment: Awesome. Thanks Wilfred!